# Объединить 2 ячейки с помощью JS

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Объясню на примере.

У нас есть таблица:

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Status1</th>
<th>Status2</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>+</td><td>-</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>-</td><td>+</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>+</td><td>+</td></tr>
</tbody>
</tbody>
```

Задача - объединить столбец 2 и столбец 3 (Status1 и Status2) таким образом, чтобы если в Status1 или Status2 есть +, то показывать +, иначе - минус.

В итоге должно получиться так:

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Status</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>+</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>-</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>+</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>+</td></tr>
</tbody>
</tbody>
```

В JS плохо разбираюсь, больше по PHP, поэтому и прошу помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я бы сделал так: http://jsfiddle.net/xutpw/2/

есть данные вида:

```
[
    {Id: 1,  Status1: '+', Status2: '-'},
    {Id: 2,  Status1: '-', Status2: '-'}, 
    {Id: 3,  Status1: '-', Status2: '+'}, 
    {Id: 4,  Status1: '+', Status2: '+'}
];
```

и уже исходя из этих данных, я бы формировал 2 таблицы

Comment: спасибо.
данные формируются с помощью json?

Comment: естественно